# Extjs Paging- All records are displayed instead of pageSize

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd

I have a LiveSearchGridPanel in extjs. I am trying to fill up my grid with soundcloud query result. I have set pageSize and also the limit param. 
I am getting 25 results and I want to divide them in 5 pages.

This is my Store:

```
  store : Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
        model : "ThemeApp.model.peopleModel",
        storeId: 'peopleStore2',
        pageSize: 5,                    
        autoLoad: {start: 0, limit: 25},
        autoSync: true,
   }),
```

This is my paging toolbar:

```
{               
xtype : 'pagingtoolbar',            
store : 'peopleStore2', 
dock : 'bottom', 
displayInfo : true,
emptyMsg : 'No data to display',
}
```

This is my Model:

```
        fields: [ {name: 'id', type: 'auto'},
                  {name: 'kind', type: 'auto'},
                  {name: 'created_at', type: 'auto'},
                  {name: 'title', type: 'auto'}],
proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            idParam: "id",

            url: 'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?q=nusrat&client_id=0b19b8dc2526b43eae19f03b2eab6798',
            headers: {'Content-Type': "application/json" },     

            reader: {
            type: 'json',
            totalProperty: 'total'

            }
```

I have found a lot of questions on stack overflow regarding same problem and I have tried solution of all those but nothing works for me that's whiy I am creating a new one.
Can you tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to load page wise data from that sound cloud url. You can, however, achieve pagination locally on the records you've loaded from that url. See this documentation for PagingMemoryProxy http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy

Comment: @yellen I want to do it in local server. I was testing soundcloud just for testing. 
Can you tell me how to do it on local server?

Comment: You'll get a better picture from here - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging

This is for version 5.0 but the same will also be available for 5.1 or 4.x

Comment: @yellen I have write this code by following the link you suggested. It would be great if you point/solve errors in my code.

Comment: Your server has to handle the pagination -if you follow the example.

Comment: @yellen Okay thanks, I'll get back to this thread once I'll be able to make my server handle pagination